# How to check whether the process with given ID still exists?

Tags: .net, wolfram-mathematica

Good day,

I am new to `.NET` and I am accessing `.NET` through Wolfram *Mathematica* with [`NETLink`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NETLink/tutorial/Overview.html) package. I need to define a `.NET` function that returns information whether the process with given ID still exists.

A typical way to define a `.NET` function through [`NETLink`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NETLink/tutorial/Overview.html) is as follows:

```
Needs["NETLink`"];
LoadNETType["System.Diagnostics.Process"];
killProc[procID_] := (
    proc = Process`GetProcessById[procID];
    proc@Kill[]
    );
```

The above code defines the function `killProc[procID]` that kills the process with ID `procID`. How to define a function that just checks whether the process that **had this ID before** is still exists or not? The definitions for this function probably should be done at the moment when the process still exists. And at some moment later I just wish to check whether it still exists or not.

Comment: Process IDs can be reused. How do you know whether the process with process ID `x` now is the same one it was when you last went looking for it?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It was the problem. But it seems that I have found the solution. It is the property `HasExited`: **proc = Process`GetProcessById[id]; proc@HasExited**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use the property `HasExited`:

```
Needs["NETLink`"];
LoadNETType["System.Diagnostics.Process"];
proc = Process`GetProcessById[procID];

proc@HasExited
```

This is what I searched for.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code snippet

```
Process myProcess = Process.GetProcessById( processId );
if( myProcess == null )
{
  //does not exist
}
else
{
  //process still exists
}
```

**EDIT**

I double checked now, and it seems I'm mistaken. Process.GetProcessById does not return null if process is not found, it gives a `Argument exception` instead. You should use this code snippet instead:

```
public void ProcessExists( int myProcessId )
{
  return Process.GetProcesses().Where( p => p.Id == myProcessId).Any());
}
```

Comment: @Øyvind Such approach in *Mathematica* gives a ".NET exception" error if the process does not exist. It does give the answer but this is not a good way to do... I need a `.NET` function that just returns something like `True` or `False`. The second problem is that I wish to check existence of a process that was existing earlier, not just to check whether there is another process with the same ID.

Comment: I changed it into a method for you now that return true of false depending on whether the process exist or not. If it's the same process that you killed, or a new one that got the same ID will be hard to check. One thing you can do is to store the process name of the ID you kill as well as the ID, and then when checking, see if both ID and name match. A new process with the same name getting the same ID will be highly unlikely, so it should probably be good enough.

Comment: Oh, I just found myself what I need! It is the property `HasExited`: **proc = Process`GetProcessById[id];
proc@HasExited**. Thank you in any way!

Comment: @Alexey - I didn't know myself that this method existed. So then I learned something myself of this :) Good catch!